# Why does replace not accept a motion?

Tags: cursor-motions, replace, object-motions

A lot of operator like `delete`, `change`, `indent`, `switch-case` accept a motion to apply on.

For example, let say I want to replace the current word with all letter `a`, I do:

```
viwra
```

Compared to the imagined:

```
riwa
```

Why isn't it the same for the `replace` command?

It's obviously by design, do you know the reason behind this choice?

Comment: Because it already takes another argument?

Comment: Makes sens, but it's strange that vim does not accept a {motion} followed by something else (if that's the explanation)

Comment: I think you mean `viwra`. Uppercase 'R' replaces the whole line regardless of what's visually selected.

Comment: What if you want to replace the character under the cursor with i, move to the next word, and insert something after the first letter?

Comment: `r` is a command, not an operator. Operators operate on a text-object or motion but that's not the case for `r`, like `i` or `a` or `o`.

Comment: @Lawrence, I'd do the same as when I try to uppercase only one letter: `gUl`, so `rli`. It's not ideal, but at least I think it gives consistency.

Comment: @romainl: good point, I would never think of applying a motion to `i`,`a` or `o`.

Comment: Wouldn't `graiw` be better?  Would be similar to `g~iw`.  I don't think the behaviour you want is better than being able to replace the current character with two keystrokes.

Comment: @Lawrence, you're right, I'm just guessing here what would make sens. But obviously as romainl said, commands are not operators, I think the explanation ends here... As for a workaround, mapping gr could be a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually. There is **no** reason, apart from things being as they are, that would be against an `r` operator. The simple fact that `viwra` works means that `riwa` *could* work. The reason is simply a historical one, but there is nothing against an alternative implementation. It can help 'filling' some area defined by a motion/text-object with a single character.

I think the main idea against it was that e.g. `ri` to replace the current character with `i` was found more useful (= often needed) than an operator which for that case would need more letters (`rli` would have probably sufficed for the above example: 'replace' operation + 'move one char to the right' motion + replacement char).

But what's nice with Vim is that anybody can come up with this alternative :) `rri` as "replace all chars in line with `i`" doesn't look too bad :)

Answer (score 2):

`Replace` is a specific type of situation, that I don't believe is equivalent to the others you listed that take motions. `r` can take an optional count, but the action is the same. `3ra` replaces 3 characters with the letter "a". In its current state, adding a motion would only allow for the repetition of the replace action. You could "replace word with the letter 'a'" but anything else would be the equivalent to just doing a `change`.

You can achieve the same outcome using visual selection. `viwra` would do a "Visual selection in word, replace with 'a'". You'll notice that a lot of other actions that only provide counts, have the same sort of "visual selection replacement for motion".

`R` version of replace is a mode so there wouldn't be any type of motion, similar to how there is no motion for any other mode.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but a piece of code I used to "simulate" the functionality of an operator with `r`:

```
function! ROperator()
  call inputsave()
  let l:replace_pattern = input('Replace > ')
  call inputrestore()

  if len(l:replace_pattern) != 3
    throw "Bad pattern size (expected 3)"
  endif

  let l:motion = strpart(replace_pattern, 0, 2)
  let l:char = strpart(replace_pattern, 2, 2)

  execute "normal! v".l:motion."r".l:char

endfunction

nnoremap gr :call ROperator()<CR>
```

This can be used like so (`[]` is the cursor position):

```
 This is a se[n]tence.

 griw*

 This is a **[*]****.
```

Comment: How can this be extended to be dot-repeated without entering the character again? Could the plugin repeat.vim from tpope be helpful?

Comment: I don't think it is, as it is using a normal mode command and from https://superuser.com/a/429921/367359 it doesn't seem it's possible... But I haven't had a look at repeat.vim though, it could work...

Comment: Have a look into the LaTeX plugin [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex). This supports dot repeat for the command `change surrounding environment` (default map `cse`) which also takes input from the commandline. It uses tpope's repeat.vim. However, I couldn't figure out how to re-use the code from `https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/autoload/vimtex/env.vim`, in particular of  `<plug>(vimtex-env-change)`.